Не работают npm и npx при установленном Node.js v20.17.0
Установил Node.js v20.17.0w с оф. сайта https://nodejs.org/en/download/prebuilt-installer, при попытке вызвать версию npm в папке на этом же диске выдает тонну ошибок. Переустанавливал все несколько раз, но не помогает, соответственно разворачивать React и т.д. не представляется возможным.
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli\validate-engines.js:31
    throw err
    ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fs-minipass\lib\index.js:136:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1548:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1104:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\log-file.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1548:10)

Node.js v20.17.0


при попытке вызвать версию npm - При какой команде такая ошибка?

Попробуйте удалить текущий npm
npm uninstall -g npm

И установить заново новый
npm install -g npm

